# Xamarin Forms: How to change background from gray on selected item in listview, iOS

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am unable to change the background color on the selected item in a listview from gray on iOS. I am using Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.192-pre2, before I used 2.3.3 with the same result.

I have tried to impalement a custom renderer:

```
using App.Views.View.List;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NoSelectionViewCell), typeof(App.iOS.Views.List.NoSelectionViewCellRenderer))]
namespace App.iOS.Views.List
{
    public class NoSelectionViewCellRenderer: ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None; // This does nothing ...
            // cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Blue; // This does nothing ...
            // cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default; // This does nothing ...
            // cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray; // This does nothing ...
            if (cell != null)
            {
                 cell.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView
                 {
                     BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red, // This doesn't matter ...
                 };
            }

            UpdateBackground(cell, item); // This doesn't seem to do anything ...

            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

I want the background to be transparent.

Comment: You know that you can do this without the custom renderer. Is there a reason you are going with this approach?

Comment: Because everything I have tried in XAML and in the shared forms project for setting the background of the ViewCell do not work on iOS. I am setting the background of the ViewCell in my shared project, which works as long as the item is not selected, when it becomes selected the background turns gray, on iOS. On Android everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in my projects is to deselect the item once it is selected. It solves the problem that you cannot select an item already selected (for example, you select an item, you navigate to new page then you navigate back and the item is already selected. In this case, you cannot reselect the same item).

This is how I do it:

```
private void ListView_OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SelectedItem == null)
        return;

    //we do stuff here

    // We deselect the item so that the background is not greyed when we come back
    ListView.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

This is the xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" 
              ItemSelected="ListView_OnItemSelected">
</ListView>
```

Comment: With that solution the list item's background will flash gray, do you know any solution for that or do I have to live with that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Apple/Xamarin fixed anything but the no selection style is definitely working for me, exert included, but see working sample project:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using UIKit;
using ListviewNoSelection.Controls;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NoSelectionCell), typeof(ListviewNoSelection.iOS.Renderer.NoSelectionCellRenderer))]
namespace ListviewNoSelection.iOS.Renderer
{
    public class NoSelectionCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/conrad90909/NoSelectionViewCell

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18589890)

Comment: Duly noted Patrick, and edited.  What I was attempting to say though was his original code works really... I just included the sample project in case something else in the background was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine.

I just changed the export renderer like this :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(NoSelectionViewCellRenderer))]
```

I verified that the breakpoint is hit and it work fine. I commented this line

```
cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
```

And the selected background is red. Your code is fine!

Comment: I made the same changes as you did, and create a simple listview. I put a breakpoint in the renderer and verified that it is hit, but the background is still gray. I am testing on an iPhone 5s.